# show loading screen if validation passes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Validator (http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) for form validation.

I want to show a loading screen div when the form is submitted but only if it passes validation, at the moment the loading screen just appears when the form is submitted and you can't return to the form.

The code I'm using at the moment to test for validation...

```
$('#defaultForm').submit(function(){
    $(defaultForm).data('bootstrapValidator').validate();
    if($(defaultForm).data('bootstrapValidator').isValid())
    { 
      $('#ajax-loading').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code seems logical, according to their docs. But I'm not sure how it runs at all - the `defaultForm` variable in `$(defaultForm)` isn't defined, so it's surely failing. You tagged this question with AJAX. But you didn't mention it. So is this form being submitted and an AJAX request is used instead of a normal form submission? If so, that's really important to include and explain. In that case, you need to know when the AJAX request completes, and then call `$('#ajax-loading').hide();`

Comment: Apologies, the ajax tag was incorrect. The script is not using AJAX. The form involves a file upload, the loading screen is displayed whilst that happens.

Comment: Well then I guess I'm confused. If you are submitting a normal form, it will reload the page. When the submission completes and the page reloads, the loading screen div will be hidden again. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, added the show div and form submit code to the submitHandler part like so.

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
         document.getElementById("defaultForm").submit();
         $('#ajax-loading').show();
        },
```